# Is there any way to store client ip in Redis?

Tags: redis

Can I save client IP in `SET` command in Redis by Redis' engine?

Something like this:

```
SET my_key $client_ip
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you don't know your `$client_ip`, you can do the following:

1. Set a unique name for your connection to Redis with [`CLIENT SETNAME`](http://redis.io/commands/client-setname)
2. Get the client list with [`CLIENT LIST`](http://redis.io/commands/client-list)
3. Locate the line with your connection's name and extract the IP address
4. Use the obtained IP address in your `SET` command

**Example**

```
127.0.0.1:6379> client getname
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> client setname FreddyFrog
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> client getname
"FreddyFrog"
127.0.0.1:6379> client list
id=4 addr=127.0.0.1:49426 fd=6 name=FreddyFrog age=25 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=client
```

Comment: Great answer - have a vote! I added an example for folks to see.

Comment: Thanks - was planning on adding the example once I got to my laptop but your saved me the work :)

Comment: "client info" may be a quicker way to do the same thing on Redis versions supporting "client info"